# How to use each method to put result in view

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections

Instead of creating a `foreach` loop I want to iterate over the results and
I am using the `each()` method:

```
$collection = Comment::all();

$comment =  $collection->each(function ($comment){
    dd($comment->comment);
});
```

when I `dd()` I get:

> "Hatter; 'so I should think."

But when I pass to view:

```
 return view('welcome')->with('comment',$comment);
```

I get

```
[{"id":1,"post_id":5,"comment":"Hatter; 'so I should think.","created_at":"2018-04-05 15:23:20","updated_at":"2018-04-05 15:23:20"},

{"id":2,"post_id":5,"comment":"Alice gently remarked;.","created_at":"2018-04-05 15:23:20","updated_at":"2018-04-05 15:23:20"},
```

and so on..

This is the view:

```
{{$comment}}
```

I want to iterate through the collection and put data into `$comment` and then show it in the view.

Comment: You are passing the whole collection to the view. Which comment do you want in the view?

Comment: i what to iterate  throught each method and to put comment result in $comment and to pass that to the view?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple like this.
Iterate then `->` following the property name

```
 @foreach($comment as $row)
    <li>{{ $row->id }}</li>
    <li>{{ $row->post_id}}</li>
    //AND SO ON
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Yes, but i what to do without foreach.I what to use each() for that and  put in $comment adn pass that in view